# Печать таблицы из браузера

Tags: javascript, печать

Здравствуйте!

У меня к Вам такой вопрос:
php скрипт генерирует некую таблицу и выводит ее на экран.
Таблица из нескольких столбцов и строк (товарная накладная).
Мне нужно как то ее распечатать прямо из браузера, нажав кнопку "печать накладной",
которая расположена ниже этой таблицы.
Распечатать нужно именно таблицу а не всю html страницу вместе с кнопкой "печать накладной".

Если есть способ и Вы его знаете, подскажите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

Определите css-правила для media="print", в которых скройте элементы, которые не должны печататься.

Comment: эх, не успел написать)